# Android: Play Video unable to open content error

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to make a functionality wherein on click of button video will be played. This video would be located in memory card of mobile.I am unable to assign proper path. Currently I am using this code

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("/sdcard/media/1.mp4");
```

How can I give correct path ?

Logcat gives:

```
02-18 22:55:26.629: W/VideoView(23792): Unable to open content: /sdcard/media/1.mp4
02-18 22:55:26.629: W/VideoView(23792): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
```

Comment: what is in your logcat?

Comment: I have edited the question to give logcat text

Comment: Hi @user3726986 do you find any solution? I am getting the same issue

Comment: @SyedaZunairah, Have you asked for permission to use external storage?